# A way to know if only one cell is selected or an entire row is selected in a Ext Js 4.2.2 grid

Tags: extjs4.2

I'm pretty new to Ext Js 4.
My question is "is there a way to know (a method or something) if a row is selected or just one cell is selected in a Ext Js 4.2.2 grid?"
I need to run some code if there is only one cell selected and run totally different code if the entire row is selected. 
Also I need to change the type of selection in that grid, I mean if I press click on a cell, the entire row gets selected, but if I press double click on a cell, only that cell is selected.
I have no idea how to do that, so I would appreciate any kind of help.

So what I really need to do is to copy to the clipboard the content of the cell (if there is only one cell selected) or the content of the row (if the entire row is selected) and permit to the user to switch the selection mode from cell selection to row selection by clicking or double clicking one cell. I already know I have to use CTRL C in a hidden 'textarea' where the text is already selected in order to achieve the copy to the clipboard.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use celldblclick for double click on cell and itemclick for click on record. If you click on record that record will be selected automatically if disableSelection is false.

You can add listeners to these events to do your own logic.

celldblclick is available since version 4.1.0
itemclick is available since version 4.0.0

--Sridhar

Comment: But how can I change from selType: 'rowmodel' to selType:'cellmodel' ? Just setting grid.selType to those values doesnt seems to work